# How to interpret trace file in Tiles mode for HEVC

Tags: hevc

I have been working with HEVC Encoder. Can anyone tell me about how to interpret the trace file we get after using HM tool Encoder in Tiles mode?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Which version of HM are you using? Can you show an example of your trace file? What is the command you use to encode and get the trace file? etc.

Comment: I am using HM version 10. My trace file looks something like this.           0 14 130038 1 19;
2 11 23045 1 1;
1 10 1350 1 2;
with leftmost column as frame number.  I encoded using the procedure showed in this link https://codesequoia.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/make-your-first-hevc-stream/                      Any help will be appreciated. Thank You